# Eclipse Version tagging

Tags: eclipse, versioning, release-management

I am developing an Android App by myself. Using Eclipse. I did not defined any repository on the web, nor am I using CVS (there is no team). I have all the code sources locally on my computer.

How do I go about tagging the current source with a version number?
Is it customary to tag once when stable and again when ready for release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using some sort of version control.  You can get a free account on github and store your code there.  But using version control is independent of how you use versions in your plugin.

This link contains the Eclipse guidelines for versioning:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering

To summarize:

1. Pre-release, use something like 0.x.x.qualifier
2. First major release will be 1.0.0.qualifier
3. bump up the micro version (third number) for bug fixes
   4, bump up the minor version (second number) for new functionality that maintains backwards compatibility
4. bump up the major version for big changes that break compatibility
5. The qualifier should be converted to a unique id by the build process.  Typically, it is some variant of a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the numbering schemes. The important thing you are saying is that there is no way I can manage my app development completely within my PC, that I have to handle version control through the net.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. There's no reason why you can't set up a git repo locally and use that to version your code.  But, I'd say that's pretty silly.  The strength of version control is that it is remote and you have some amount of protection if something bad happens to your machine.

Comment: Are all people comfortable putting their code in some external server? :::: I think I can manage to backup this data as I backup anything important on my PC.

Comment: Put git on your local box.  It might not have the safety of remote backup but you can still version your code so you don't go and "fix"/break it.  And if you want to later it is easy (one command) to push it to a server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  The Local History in Eclipse is not a substitute for a real source control management system.

Comment: Were you replying to me or to Andrew? "You don't" what?

Comment: You don't "go about tagging the current source with a version number" when the code sources only exist locally.

Comment: So you are basically saying the same as Andrew, that I cannot develop an application completely within my PC, I need some sort of web support for version control.

Comment: No.  If you're on Linux, for example, it's trivial to use your own machine as if it were a remote CVS server.  It's just that the local history within Eclipse is neither designed nor equipped for assigning a version number to resources in a way you can reliably get back to 5 or 10 years down the road.

Comment: I never though Local history can be used, at least AFAIK it works individually for each file, not for a group of files in sync. Unfortunately I am not in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172363/andrew-eisenberg) that it's worth adding your code to a version control system.  If you aren't comfortable with placing it on github, you can still use git in a local git repo so your code is source controlled.

@Andrew also mentioned the breakdown of plugin and feature version numbers.  When building headless with PDE Build or exporting through the PDE UI, you can at build time change the qualifier part of the version.  It's an option in the PDE export wizard, and for a PDE headless build with no source control can be overridden with `forceContextQualifier` in the `build.properties` file.

Comment: Wow! While most of the details you guys are talking are over my head. I appreciate the advices and I will give  local GIT a shot. If you have a starting link for me to dig into local GIT setup it will be appreciated as well.